# Buscar elementos da lista com strings parciais

Tags: c#, string, lista

Tenho uma `List<string>` que recebe o número do telefone de todos os contatos do telefone, até aí sem problema, porém quero realizar umas operações com os elementos dessa lista, mas estou com alguns problemas.

Um exemplo de resultado possível:

```
lst = {"*126", "+55 3412345678", "12345678", "87654321", "3498761232"};
```

Se observarem, todos são números de telefones, e armazenei como string, para ficar mais fácil. Agora tenho que realizar uma busca nessa lista, em todos elementos da mesma (não sei quanto elementos a lista terá, pois depende da agenda do usuário).

**Exemplo:**
Usuário digita **123** no textbox `num` e ao apertar do botão faço a busca na minha lista, o resultado deve ser:

```
+55 3412345678
12345678
3498761232
```

Pois se observarmos, são os únicos elementos da lista que contém a string digitada (`123`).

Então resumidamente, como fazer para buscar em uma lista de tamanho indeterminado, uma string que pode estar em qualquer lugar do elemento (inicio, meio, fim, etc), a busca deve retornar no máximo 3 valores, ou seja, se tivermos outro elemento como por exemplo `51234251`, apesar de conter `123` ele não seria retornado, pois já encontramos 3 elementos com `123` antes dele.

Desculpem se ficou confuso, foi o jeito mais detalhado que consegui relatar, em resumo, é buscar uma string parcial em uma lista e retornar os três primeiros elementos que contêm aquela string. Porém não consegui realizar tal tarefa, espero que alguém possa me ajudar, pois já foi um trabalhão e tempão para descobrir como pegar o número dos contatos e armazenar na lista.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Usa a extensão [`Enumerable.Where`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534803(v=vs.100).aspx) para filtrar a lista por um predicado.
- Neste caso, o predicado é: "a string deve conter '123'". Para isso podemos usar `String.Contains`
- Usa [`Enumerable.Take`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb503062(v=vs.100).aspx) para obter os primeiros `n` elementos do resultado e descartar os restantes.

```
var input = "123";

var filtered = list.Where(s => s.Contains(input))
                   .Take(3)
                   .ToList();
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/R0tiro

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, nunca pensaria que seria tão simples assim, obrigado!

Comment: Só complementando esse recurso que o dcastro utilizou é o famoso LINQ (Language Integrated Query ou, em português, Linguagem de consulta integrada). Para você ter uma ideia do poder do LINQ aqui nesse endereço tem um exemplo de cada um dos recursos que o LINQ oferece: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b